# Python Script for Just logging in to Instagram

Tags: python, cookies, instagram

Here I have written an Python script to login in to Instagram...but problem is that i can not get cookies and post them again so it is giving me error to enable cookies before login so please someone help me at this script

```
import requests
import re
import cookielib

emsg='you are browsing in Private Mode'
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'https://instagram.com/'
url2 = 'https://instagram.com/accounts/login/'
values = {'username': 'username',
              'password': 'password'}

session = requests.Session()

jar1=requests.post(url2,headers=user_agent)
print jar1.cookies
r = requests.post(url2,cookies=jar1.cookies,headers = user_agent, data=values)

print r.request.headers['Cookie']
target = open('filename.html', 'w')
target.write(r.content)
target.close ()


if re.findall(emsg,r.content):
    print "\n\n\n\n Enable cookies please\n\n\n\n"
else:
    print"\n\n\n\nSomething is changed\n\n\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Requests session object automatically takes care of cookies -

```
import requests
import re

emsg='you are browsing in Private Mode'
user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

url = 'https://instagram.com/'
url2 = 'https://instagram.com/accounts/login/'
values = {'username': 'username',
              'password': 'password'}

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(user_agent)
session.get(url2)

r = session.post(url2, data=values)

print r.request.headers['Cookie']
target = open('filename.html', 'w')
target.write(r.content)
target.close()

if re.findall(emsg,r.content):
    print "\n\n\n\n Enable cookies please\n\n\n\n"
else:
    print"\n\n\n\nSomething is changed\n\n\n\n"
```

Comment: my friend I tried that but it is not working....i am steel getting error to enable cookies and do not use private mode in your browser

Comment: Please try to find out what all header values are being sent.

Comment: these are header :


{'content-length': '7068', 
'content-language': 'en', 'set-cookie': 'csrftoken=2ca1591ac14d2330422a2b49055e2d8f; expires=Thu, 09-Jun-2016 13:26:36 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/', 
'expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'vary': 'Cookie, Accept-Language', 'last-modified': 'Thu, 11 Jun 2015 13:26:36 GMT', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 
'cache-control': 'private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'date': 'Thu, 11 Jun 2015 13:26:36 GMT'
, 'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'content-type': 'text/html'}

Comment: Can we use, already existing cookie to login and authenticate

Comment: Yes. You need to read those cookies and do `session.cookies.update(<read_cookies_dict>)`